# localtime() takes 24 times more than gmtime() performance issue on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux

Due to performance issues on a project I made the following test program (even used different variables for sanity check):

```
int main()
{

struct tm *timeinfo;
time_t rawtime;
clock_t begin, end, begin1, end1,begin2,end2;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
}

end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time elapsed using localtime()      : %fs\n", time_spent);    
//--------------------------------

begin1 = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = gmtime(&rawtime);
}

end1 = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end1 - begin1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time elapsed using gmtime()         : %fs\n", time_spent);           
//--------------------------------

begin2 = clock();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    time ( &rawtime );
    localtime_r( &rawtime, timeinfo);
}

end2 = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end2 - begin2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("Time elapsed using localtime_r()    : %fs\n", time_spent);


return 0;
}
```

The results I get are very strange, localtime takes ~24 times more time, the localtime_r() function seems to take less than localtime(), but still a lot more than gmtime():

```
Time elapsed using localtime()      : 0.958033s
Time elapsed using gmtime()         : 0.038769s
Time elapsed using localtime_r()    : 0.860276s
```

I've compiled it with gcc 5 as well as 4.x version, I've used linux Mint (updated to this day) and CentOS5. Also it's been tested on different physical machines and the performance difference is similar.

Why is there such a (huge) performance difference?

Comment: _these two function is similar_...the fact they return similar values does not mean that implementation is the same....

Comment: I meant the performance difference is similar, I've edited the text to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: What is your question? I don't see one.

Comment: Is there difference in the timings if you use localtime_r instead of localtime?

Comment: What I meant is that those function are similar in the output, but different in implementation. So you are only testing performances, nothing more...

Comment: Try running your code with `TZ=UTC` and see if that makes a difference. If it does, you'll have some info about what is costly in `localtime`.

Comment: The unit `ms` is wrong, the code outputs time in seconds.

Comment: http://ideone.com/0yx5LP anyway why would you need to call either function in a tight loop?

Comment: You're wondering why different functions that do different things have different performance? Isn't the answer obvious? Because they are different and do different things. How is this a "performance issue"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run this code under `perf record` and then do `perf report` you will notice that `localtime` calls `getenv("TZ")` on each iteration. Whereas `gmtime` does not.

Looking into the source code of `glibc` confirms the callgraphs:

```
gmtime
    __tz_convert(, 0, )
       tzset_internal(0, 1)
mktime
    __tz_convert(, 1, )
       tzset_internal(1, 1)
           getenv("TZ")
```

See `glibc` source code of [`localtime`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/localtime.c;h=07dd67ca71be9e2447389eee8aa28af601dc286e;hb=HEAD), 
[`gmtime`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/gmtime.c;h=049d551cdf4fe38bbbbc0285e64a72a0ba95ba5d;hb=HEAD) and
[`__tz_convert`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/tzset.c;h=eb420699c42a49b4763eb1303e033ca448c4a1db;hb=HEAD#l605).

`perf report`:

```
Samples: 78K of event 'cycles:u', Event count (approx.): 21051445406
  Children      Self       Samples  Command  Shared Object      Symbol                          ▒
+   99.48%     0.59%           349  test     test               [.] main                        ▒
+   99.48%     0.00%             0  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __libc_start_main           ▒
+   99.48%     0.00%             0  test     test               [.] _start                      ▒
+   98.02%     7.07%          4208  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __tz_convert                ◆
-   24.51%    23.87%         20812  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] getenv                      ▒
   - 23.87% _start                                                                              ▒
        __libc_start_main                                                                       ▒
        main                                                                                    ▒
        __tz_convert                                                                            ▒
        getenv                                                                                  ▒
   + 0.64% getenv                                                                               ▒
+   22.41%    12.75%          9877  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __tzfile_compute            ▒
+   15.49%    15.49%          8025  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __offtime                   ▒
+   12.72%     6.28%          5476  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __tzfile_read               ▒
+    9.66%     3.54%          3086  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __tzstring                  ▒
+    8.36%     1.40%          1221  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __strdup                    ▒
+    7.68%     3.38%          2946  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] free                        ▒
+    5.98%     3.07%          2682  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] malloc                      ▒
+    4.96%     0.68%           611  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __xstat64                   ▒
+    4.30%     4.30%          3750  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] _int_free                   ▒
+    4.28%     4.28%          3731  test     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] entry_SYSCALL_64            ▒
+    4.08%     4.08%          3564  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] strlen                      ▒
+    3.64%     3.64%          3168  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __memcmp_sse2               ▒
+    2.91%     2.91%          2561  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] _int_malloc                 ▒
+    1.25%     1.25%          1094  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] __memcpy_sse2               ▒
+    0.68%     0.68%           587  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] localtime                   ▒
     0.26%     0.26%           222  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] 0x000000000001f910          ▒
     0.18%     0.18%            37  test     test               [.] gmtime@plt                  ▒
     0.15%     0.15%           126  test     test               [.] localtime@plt               ▒
     0.11%     0.11%            23  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] gmtime                      ▒
     0.01%     0.01%             6  test     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __irqentry_text_start       ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             3  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] _dl_lookup_symbol_x         ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             5  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] do_lookup_x                 ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             2  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] _dl_relocate_object         ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             1  test     libc-2.23.so       [.] 0x000000000001f8e8          ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             1  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] strlen                      ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             1  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] _dl_debug_initialize        ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             1  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] _dl_start                   ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             1  test     [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] page_fault                  ▒
     0.00%     0.00%             6  test     ld-2.23.so         [.] _start
```

Answer (score 0):

Parts of the work of `localtime` and `gmtime` are cached.

So only the first call to one of these functions does the real work, i.e. read `/etc/localtime` to get the local timezone. This action is performed also for `gmtime()`, even if it might not be necessary.

To get reliable results place a call to `gmtime` or `localtime` before the first measuring. The performance of both functions should be similar then.

Comment: How can the result of a call to a time function be cached? Is the cache entry accompanied by a CPU tick count or summat? And invalidated after _n_ ticks?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Parts of the work is cached, not the result itself. I corrected the misleading term.

Comment: Well, I will delete the answer if anything is incorrect, no problem... Mind to tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You wouldn't cache the time, but you might cache the time zone data you need to compute the result based on the system time that you retrieve in each call. I don't know that's what it's doing, but I'd be considering it if I was writing `localtime()` myself.

Comment: @MatthewWalton: I'd hope the API I was using within the `localtime()` implementation took care of that for me but, failing that, yes agreed

Comment: @Ctx: Even a timezone cache has to be invalidated at some point. Changing the system timezone takes immediate effect in applications, in my experience.