# Why this `__xstat64` cost this much in perf?

Tags: c++, performance, perf

I have a C++ program which parses timestamps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>


void one(){
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("log2.txt");
    unsigned long long x = 0;
    while (!fin.eof()) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(fin, line);
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
        int milli_second;
        int timezone_hour;
        int timezone_min;

        std::sscanf(line.data(), "[%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d.%d %d:%d]", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &milli_second,
            &timezone_hour, &timezone_min);

        std::tm time {};
        time.tm_year = year - 1900;
        time.tm_mon = month - 1;
        time.tm_mday = day;
        time.tm_hour = hour;
        time.tm_min = minute;
        time.tm_sec = second;

        time_t ctime = mktime(&time) * 1000; 
        x += ctime;
        x %= 192929;
    }
    printf("%llu", x);
    fin.close();
}

int main(int c, char *argv[]){
    bool fi = false;
    printf("c %d\n", c);
    if(c == 2){
        if(argv[1][0] != 'n'){
            fi = true;
            printf("fi\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
    if(fi){
        while(1){
            one();
        }
    }else{
        one();
    }
}
```

Data can be generated like with code

```
#coding: utf8

import time, random, string

def one2(prev_t):
    t = prev_t + random.uniform(1, 100)
    ts = time.strftime("[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.123 +08:00]", time.localtime(t))
    msg_len = int(random.uniform(2, 20))
    msg = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(msg_len))
    level = random.choice(["DEBUG", "INFO"])
    return t, "{} [{}] [<unknown>] {}\n".format(ts, level, msg)

def make_log():
    t = time.time()
    with open("log3.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in range(1, 10000000):
            t, s = one2(t)
            f.write("{}".format(s))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_log()
```

Now I want to perf that with the following codes.

```
g++ -g -O0 t.cpp -o tttzzz
./tttzzz &
ps aux | grep tttzzz
export TPID=$(ps aux | grep 'tttzzz' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
echo "TPID" $TPID
timeout -s INT 8s perf record -F 99 -e "cpu-clock" -g -p $TPID
perf report
```

However, I found result it like this, seems that `__xstat64` cost too much time.

```
+   50.89%     0.00%  [.] __xstat64                                                                                          __xstat64+140186421776405       ◆
+   42.20%     0.00%  [k] system_call_fastpath                                                                               system_call_fastpath+18446603336▒
+   41.39%     0.00%  [k] sys_newstat                                                                                        sys_newstat+18446603336221188110▒
+   39.00%     0.00%  [k] SYSC_newstat                                                                                       SYSC_newstat+1844660333622118814▒
+   35.34%     0.00%  [k] vfs_fstatat                                                                                        vfs_fstatat+18446603336221188195▒
+   35.22%     0.00%  [k] user_path_at                                                                                       user_path_at+1844660333622118811▒
+   31.43%     0.00%  [k] user_path_at_empty                                                                                 user_path_at_empty+1844660333622▒
+   31.11%     0.00%  [k] filename_lookup                                                                                    filename_lookup+1844660333622118▒
+   19.80%     0.00%  [.] _IO_vsscanf                                                                                        _IO_vsscanf+140186421776487
+    3.07%     0.00%  [.] main                                                                                               main+4194414

...
     0.72%     0.22%  t        [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] path_get                                                                                             ▒
+    0.72%     0.72%  t        [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] generic_fillattr                                                                                     ▒
     0.69%     0.69%  t        [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string                                                                       ▒
+    0.69%     0.00%  t        libc-2.17.so         [.] __GI___libc_read                                                                                     ▒
+    0.67%     0.00%  t        [unknown]            [.] 0x00007fff4122a180                                                                                   ▒
     0.67%     0.67%  t        libc-2.17.so         [.] parse_tzname                                                                                         ▒
+    0.66%     0.66%  t        t                    [.] one
```

My question is:

1. Where is `__xstat64` called? I think it must be child of some function like `main` or `one`?
2. Why this function cost that much, while main cost only 3%?

Comment: `stat` is likely being called as an implementation detail of `std::ifstream::open`

Comment: @CoryKramer But why it does not belong to `main`?  In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544774/localtime-takes-24-times-more-than-gmtime-performance-issue-on-linux) post, `main` has child that cost more than 99% time

Comment: Random guess: the compiler has inlined `one` into your `main` function. Since you call `one` over and over, it stands to reason the contents of the file are in  memory cache, but the OS still has to make a system call (`stat`) to verify that the file is still there.

Comment: @Botje But I used -O0, I don't think `one` is inlined, BTW, I can found the function `one`, I don't listed above.

Comment: pastebin and similar links are not sufficient for SO questions about code.  Use a code block in the question.  If you want to show it running, a link to https://godbolt.org/ *as well* as the code block can be good.  ([Godbolt allows non-shortened "full links" which insure against link rot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked/319594#319594) - use that especially if a link isn't a trivial copy/paste of code that's already in the SO post.)

Comment: When I run "strace ./tttzzz", I found tremendous logs like "stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0", I think it's called by mktime() to generate local time.

Comment: @JunGe it is reasonable, but mktime is called by main, why main has very low cpu percentage?

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, [mktime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime) is the bottleneck:

> Converts local calendar time to a time since epoch as a time_t object

Converting from local calendar time to a Unix epoch is a non-trivial task. On Linux, at least when compiling with gcc, it is implemented by libc. To understand what local time means on your machine, it uses the file [`/etc/localtime`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/localtime.html). That is why the `stat`system call shows up in `strace`.

Your strace output might differ, but this is what I got on Arch Linux after compiling with gcc 11.1.0:

```
...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2298, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2298, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2298, ...}, 0) = 0
... (repeating, as each call of "one" calls mktime, which triggers it)
```

That should explain why `__xstat64` dominates the profiling output. Note that `stat` is a system call, where you hand over the control to the Kernel. That is expensive.

As a side-note, if you know that the timestamps are UTC, then converting it to a Unix epoche is a simpler task. Yet for general local time, it is tricky as the implementation has to be aware of special cases like [daylight savings time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

> Why this function cost that much, while main cost only 3%?

Perf uses sampling and [only counts the function that is on top of the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34099915/783510). 3% in `main` means, 3% of the sample had `main` on top. Most of the samples have been recorded during the execution of `one`. Some profiling tools would therefore count `main` as hot, too. Yet, by default, perf only considers `one` to be hot, not its caller.

Comment: OK, is there any way that a caller also count's its callee's hot time? I think it will be a more direct output?

Comment: @calvin perf has a lot of options, perhaps "--call-graph" gives you the output that you expect. For example, "perf report -g 'graph,0.5,caller'"

Comment: I tried, but I still find `__xstat64` and `__lll_lock_wait_private` without its caller. I use `perf record -F 99 -g -p $TPID --call-graph=dwarf,65528 sleep 8` and `perf report -g 'graph,0.5,caller`